# how to save settings in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I installed notepad++ V 6.2.3. Never used it before.

Windows 7.

I took all defaults in installation. Opened an html file, and changed editor setting for the html file so that no coloring is there and other things using the Settings->Preferences.

Now when I open another HTML file using notepad++, I do not see the preferences I changed there. The preferences are only active when I open the first HTML file where I made the changes in.

How can I save settings so that it affects all files of type .html and not just that one file?

It is strange that there is no save settings option any where.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Notepad++ writes [settings into XML files](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Configuration_Files) automatically. Those are usually in C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++, which is "protected" area for Windows 7, requiring administrator permission to edit.

Try running Notepad++ as administrator so it can modify its config files. It's probably most convenient to edit the shortcut so it always runs as administrator.

Comment: The directory you mention does not require administrative privileges. The current user also has full access. If it is a different user then yes you will need administrative privileges.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone who came here with the same trouble I had, namely that preferences you set the last time *still* don't seem to stick in the next session despite all permissions seeming to be okay -- the actual saving occurs when you **close the program**.

That means that if it crashed, or was forced closed by a restart, it's possible your changes to settings will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up just re-installing Notepad++ directly under the "C:" drive instead of under "C:\Program Files (x86)", which solved this problem for me.  I installed shortcuts for both Python 3 and Python 2 compilers so I can use one instance of Notepadd++ to work with both.

I should also mention that this is Notepad++ v6.8.8 running on Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the followoing path

C:\Users\YourNAme\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++

Edit the file \config.xml

```
change the line  
from        <GUIConfig name="RememberLastSession">yes</GUIConfig>
Replace Yes to No
            <GUIConfig name="RememberLastSession">no</GUIConfig>
```